# jwebunit playframework functional test is stuck

Tags: junit, playframework, jwebunit

I use play-framework application, and going to use JWEBUNIT for functional testings.
There is a article that proved me to use that way:

http://nesbot.com/2011/10/16/play-framework-sample-app-JWebUnit-synchronous-ajax

Everything fine, but I have a problem with my first test, it just stuck while try to invoke it - and no any response form it.

The code where he stuck is (I use the same pieces of code like in that Article above):

```
@Test
public void testIndexRendersSuccessfully()
{
   wt.beginAt(getRoute("Application.index"));
   wt.assertElementPresent("createEvent");
   assertEquals(wt.getElementById("error").getTextContent(), "");
   assertEquals(wt.getElementById("success").getTextContent(), "");
}
```

My dependencies for jwebunit are like this:

```
require:
    - play
    - net.sourceforge.jwebunit -> jwebunit-core 3.0
    - net.sourceforge.jwebunit -> jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin 3.0
```

Do you have experiences with that or already had such problem?

Comment: why would not use the inbuilt WebDriver framework which comes with play ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer,sorry I do not like read article right to the end.

I just need to put this to conf

%test.play.pool=2